# More than one Version of manifest?

Tags: android

I wante to submit an app on Google Play Store, but it gets rejected for implementing Google Pay wrong, according to Google. When conctacting the support, they told me to "check all existing versions for the manifest declaration mentioned above"( )".  If found, please create a new build of your application (all versions with the declaration present) without this element in your manifest and you will no longer be flagged for the review."

I didnt know, there is more than one version of the manifest though. In the one, Android Studio shows me in the file explorer, the line mentioned above does not exist, so which manifest does Google mean?

Comment: are you sure they meant "versions of the manifest", not "versions of your app"? Have you uploaded (not speaking about publishing) only one version of the app so far?

Comment: Yeah, I uploaded just one Version, and this one got already rejected

Comment: And exactly what element does Google reject? Also, are you using Gradle?